# display all terms using get_sub_field() ACF

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

Hi have this code currently and it working fine, it displays get_sub_field('add_keyword', $term); when I'm in the product category.

For example I'm in "Animals" product category then I put a text on the custom field "add_keyword", it shows all the I enter in the custom fields and I'm using ACF repeater for this.

Now my concern is How to display all get_sub_field('add_keyword', $term), I want to get all the list.

currently is just displays the custom fields that were entered on the particular product categories, I just want to display all of it.

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

if ( have_rows('enter_keywords', $term) ): 
    while ( have_rows('enter_keywords', $term) ) : the_row();

    $prod_keywrds = get_sub_field('add_keyword', $term);
    echo $prod_keywrds;

    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for - do you just want to get a list of all terms in a particular taxonomy?

Comment: yes, i want to list them all using get_sub_field('add_keyword', $term) :-)

Comment: Your question title asks how to display all terms using `get_term_by` - which is for WP's taxonomies. But what you want is to get every value that you entered into the custom ACF field using `get_sub_field`? Sorry, I'm just a bit confused about what you want so I don't know how to answer :-)

Comment: Can you show us your ACF settings for this repeater (e.g. a screenshot of the repeater in the field group)?